# Is it possible to have class without variables and with methods?

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

I'm solving this problem with polymorphism. I need to print out verse of the song with 5 animals.The verse is repeated for each animal and the appropriate sound for the animal is used eg cows go “moo”, ducks go “quack” etc.  I would like to ask is it possible to have a class only with methods. In addition here is my code.

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual void PrintSong()
    {

    }
}

public class Cow : Animal
{
    public override void PrintSong()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I go \"Mooo\" (I'm a cow, I'm a cow, I'm a cow)");        
    }
}

public class Pig : Animal
{
    public override void PrintSong()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I go \"Oink\" (I'm a pig, I'm a pig, I'm a pig)");  
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Animal[] animals = new Animal[2];
    animals[0] = new Cow();
    animals[1] = new Pig();

    foreach (Animal a in animals)
    {
        a.PrintSong();
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be great, what is your main problem with that code ?

Comment: I copied your code into dotnetfiddle (and fixed the problem you have with quotes inside quotes), and it runs fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j7ctGO

Comment: Yes this is possible. Since `Animal` seems to be your base class, I suggest you to define it as `abstract`

Comment: @Bakula As @Cid said, `abstract` class would be a good fit. You will still need to derive each animals from it and you would be forced to implement the `PrintSong()` method for each animals. Right now overriding is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

A class doesnt have to have methods or fields / variables

Comment: at least one of them since an empty class makes no sense

Comment: Make no sense, but not impossible

Comment: Never said it made sense, just said it was possible