# How to recreate this solution using polymorphism and to allow inserting words from console, to replace the selected ones?

Tags: c#, loops, polymorphism, str-replace

The code given below is a simple solution to a problem, i have to do another one using polymorphism, but i am kinda new in this C# thing (almost know nothing), but i need some ideas how to recreate this code, and the code to be able to take strings from input as desired words to be switched with the default ones. Hope someone will help me, because i have absolutely no idea how to do this (i made this code by some miracle, but this task is on another level for me right now).
Thanks for everybody that will help.

```
    Console.WriteLine("BEFORE: " + value);

    string modified = value.Replace("cow", "duck").Replace("moo", "quack");
    string modified1 = value.Replace("cow", "cat").Replace("moo", "meow");
    string modified2 = value.Replace("cow", "dog").Replace("moo", "aw");
    string modified3 = value.Replace("cow", "goat").Replace("moo", "mee");
    string modified4 = value.Replace("cow", "sheep").Replace("moo", "bee");

    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified);
    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified1);
    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified2);
    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified3);
    Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified4);
}
```

}

Comment: here on OS you can finda similar problem (at least related to animals and speech :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575138/is-it-possible-to-have-class-without-variables-and-with-methods
however it lacks mechanism to provide template for text-to-speech and which parts-to-replace (both can be passed either to constructor or method or mix ... )

Answer (score 0):

In yours sample only animals where used, therefore class Animal is provided.
Also, given context for text is something resembling speech, therefore Talk method.

Matching yours sample all animals from array replace 'speech' of a cow with own.

```
public class Animal {
    protected string Kind, Says;
    protected Animal(string kind, string says) { Kind = kind; Says = says;
    }
    public string Talk(Animal impersonate, string stream) {
        return stream.Replace(impersonate.Kind, Kind).Replace(impersonate.Says, Says);
    }
}

public class Cow : Animal { public Cow() : base("cow", "moo") { } }
public class Duck : Animal { public Duck() : base("duck", "quack") { } }
public class Cat : Animal { public Cat() : base("cat", "meow") { } }
public class Dog : Animal { public Dog() : base("dog", "aw") { } }
public class Goat : Animal { public Goat() : base("goat", "mee") { } }
public class Sheep : Animal { public Sheep() : base("sheep", "bee") { } }

class Program {
    static void Sample2(string value)  {
        var cow = new Cow();
        foreach (var animal in new Animal[] {
            new Duck(),
            new Cat(),
            new Dog(),
            new Goat(),
            new Sheep()
        })
            Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + animal.Talk(cow, value));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var value = "cow does something like moo";

        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE: " + value);

        Sample1(value);
        Sample2(value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Sample1(string value) {
        string modified = value.Replace("cow", "duck").Replace("moo", "quack");
        string modified1 = value.Replace("cow", "cat").Replace("moo", "meow");
        string modified2 = value.Replace("cow", "dog").Replace("moo", "aw");
        string modified3 = value.Replace("cow", "goat").Replace("moo", "mee");
        string modified4 = value.Replace("cow", "sheep").Replace("moo", "bee");

        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified1);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified2);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified3);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:  " + modified4);
    }
}
```

As shown above, this sample will match provided input. Class and Method names can be renamed to be more generic.